# remove newlines while keeping newlines followed by another newline

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I have this text file with a lot of SQL queries. I need each query on a single line.
The queries are separated by 2 newlines for e.g. /n/n while the query itself may have single /n

Input file:

```
select * from 
table A 
where name = 'abc'

drop table A;

update table a
inner join b on a.name = b.name

fourth query
continue

fifth query
```

Expected output:

```
select * from table A where name = 'abc'

drop table A;

update table a inner join b on a.name = b.name

fourth query continue

fifth query
```

I tried this, but it prints everything on one line.

> awk '/\n/ {printf "\n%s\n",$0;next} {printf "%s ",$0}' report41.txt

I have found this pattern...

https://regex101.com/r/qNQRk5/4

But there are 2 problems. 1) I do not know how to use it in AWK and 2) the query does not contain space.

> update table ainner

Should be:

> update table a inner

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use paragraph mode:

```
$ awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' '{$1=$1} 1' ip.txt
select * from table A where name = 'abc'

drop table A;

update table a inner join b on a.name = b.name

fourth query continue

fifth query
```

- `-v RS=` empty `RS` will split input contents based on one or more empty lines
- `-v ORS='\n\n'` set output record separator as two newlines, note that this means there will be an empty line at the end of output
- `{$1=$1}` rebuild record contents, by default space/tab/newlines will be considered as input field separator
- output field separator is not changed, thus it uses the default single space between fields
- `1` idiomatic way to print contents of input record

To preserve spacing and convert only newline to space:

```
$ printf '   a\t\t\tb\n  c\n\n1  2    3' | awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' '{$1=$1} 1'
a b c

1 2 3

$ printf '   a\t\t\tb\n  c\n\n1  2    3' | awk -v FS='\n' -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' '{$1=$1} 1'
   a            b   c

1  2    3
```

Comment: Clean, simple and elegant! One problem however. When a string contains double spaces or tabs, they will be converted to a single space. This might not be wanted. The safest would be `awk 'BEGIN{RS="";ORS="\n\n";FS="\n"}{$1=$1}1'`

Comment: yeah, and it will also trim trailing/leading spaces... for given problem, I'm guessing that to be not a concern

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '{printf("%s%s",NF && FNR>1 && prev!=""?OFS:FNR>1?ORS:"",$0);prev=$0} END{print ""}'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding explanation for above.

```
awk '                                                          ##Starting awk program from here.
{
  printf("%s%s",NF && FNR>1 && prev!=""?OFS:FNR>1?ORS:"",$0)   ##Using printf command here, printing 2 strings. Checking condition if line is greater than 1
  prev=$0                                                      ##AND prev NOT equal to 1 print new line or line is grater than 1 print ORS or NULL, then print line.
}                                                              ##Setting current line value to prev variable here.
END{                                                           ##Starting END block of this code here.
  print ""                                                     ##Printing new line here.
}
'  Input_file                                                  ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```